# How to draw a 95% confidence interval (area) for residuals on a normal probability Q-Q plot in SAS?

Tags: graph, sas, confidence-interval, quantile

Under the 'CI area' I mean smth. like the one plotted on graphs in @cbeleites' [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49428) or depicted in  Ron Pearson's [post](http://exploringdatablog.blogspot.ru/2011/03/many-uses-of-q-q-plots.html).:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example of the base plot you're using?  Are you using PROC UNIVARIATE to generate the q-q plot or something else?

Comment: Joe, I use diagnostic plots in sas proc glm. What do you mean under 'an example'?

Comment: Downvoting this question until SAS code from attempts added. Recommend closing question if no additional information added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry to show my way to do this:

```
PROC SGSCATTER DATA = myData;  
   PLOT variable1*variable2 /  
       GRID REG = (DEGREE = 1 LINEATTRS = (THICKNESS = .25 pt) CLM CLI NOGROUP);  
RUN;
```